# Renaming attributes result using sequential values

Tags: visual-studio-code, rename, sequential-number

I'm facing a challenge with SVG attributes results. I need to rename several of the results of the SVG attribute in a sequential form.

```
xlink:hreef-"#path-1"
xlink:hreef-"#path-2"
xlink:hreef-"#path-3"
...
```

How can I automatize it? Exist a plugin or extension of VSCode that can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Alves, Luiz.

Comment: please make it clear what is **before** and what you want as **result**

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this extension I wrote: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false) and this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+s",             whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(xlink:href-\"#path)",
    "replace": "$1-${matchNumber}",
    "isRegex": true,
  }
}
```

It will find `(xlink:href-\"#path)` replace it withitself `$1` and append `-${matchNumber}` to it.  So the first match will get a `1`, the second match a `2` and so on.

If you wanted those 0-based you could use `${matchIndex}` instead.

[image: find-and-transform demo with matchIndex]

Comment: You can easily modify the `find` if you are starting with something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

Find and select all the items you want to rename

Find `xlink:hreef`

The **Select** > **Select All Occurrences**

Now move the multi cursors and select the part you need to replace.

Then issue command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression**

For the generator expression use: `{{=i+1}}` if you want the numbering start at 1.

You get a preview of what the result is.